# How to route requests to GeoServer on Tomcat?

Tags: geoserver, tomcat, iis, windows-server-2012

So I have a Window Server 2012 (IIS 8) that I connect to remotely (on a different network) and log in. Our goal is to be able to publish a web map serving layers from this Windows Server. I am trying to install GeoServer in a way that lets me access it on my desktop. I found [this](http://www.cartoninjas.net/post/GeoServer-production-environment-on-Windows-Server-with-IIS-and-Apache) and decided that Tomcat would be the best approach.

I have Tomcat 9 installed with the *Connector* tag edited and GeoServer 2.13 is deployed and its working great locally on the server with both on port 8080. Now, I'm stuck trying to route all traffic to http://my.test.net (step 4 in that guide). I have tried setting up *URL Rewrite* rules so it gets routed to http://localhost:8080/{R:0}. I've tried using *ARR* but I dont think I did it right.

Most of the posts (like [this](https://www.esdm.co.uk/presenting-geoserver-on-port-80-on-a-windows-iis-server) and [this](https://forums.iis.net/t/1189344.aspx?Step%20by%20Step%20guide%20to%20setting%20up%20IIS%20ARR%20with%20URL%20Re%20write%20for%20GeoServer)) and information I've found on this is almost a decade old and theres a lot of assumptions in the guides. I have never done anything like this and need a more in depth explanation.

Are there any other alternatives to Tomcat with GeoServer? Is there a way I can reroute Geoserver so it is accessible remotely? Is this still the approach I should take?

If anyone knows of any alternatives I'm not married to Tomcat and am open to other options.

Comment: can you post the rewrite rule?, if it is the one you write above if differs from the tutorial you are following.

Comment: I'm not sure the issue is with Tomcat, It's more likely at the IIS Application Request Routing end.  You shouldn't need a sub domain.

Comment: @nmtoken after more testing I dont think the firewall on the server end will allow it. I'll have to find an alternative or ask the administrators to open the ports.